# Delphi (win32) serialization libraries

Tags: delphi, serialization

Are there any Delphi serialization libraries that are capable of serializing records and arrays of records instead of classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Max you can use the [TJvAppXMLFileStorage](http://help.delphi-jedi.org/item.php?Id=149455) component from [JEDI](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/) to serialize an record or an array of records.

you can use the procedure called `WriteBinary` to store the data and `ReadBinary` to read.

unfortunately there is not much documentation on this component, so here you have an very simple example for store  a single record (for an array of records you can easily modify this source code).

### The record structure

```
type
  MyRecord= record
      Field1 : Integer;
      Field2 : Double;
      Field3 : String[20];
      Field4 : String[20];
  end;
```

### Save an record

```
Procedure SaveMyRecord(Rec : MyRecord);
var
  MyStore: TJvAppXMLFileStorage;
begin
  MyStore:= TJvAppXMLFileStorage.Create(nil);
  try
    MyStore.FileName:='C:\temp\record.xml'; 
    //this component supports store multiples objects to the same file, so you need use an identifier for you particular object, in this case i'm use the Dummy name.
    MyStore.WriteBinary('Dummy', @Rec,sizeof(Rec));
    MyStore.Xml.SaveToFile(MyStore.FileName);
  finally
    MyStore.Free;
  end;
end;
```

this procedure create an XML file like this, the data is encoded in an hexadecimal format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<Configuration>
  <Dummy>84030000000000003333333333331F400D737472696E6720746573742031000000000000000D737472696E672074657374203200000000000000000000000000</Dummy>
</Configuration>
```

### Read the persisted data

```
Procedure LoadMyRecord(var Rec : MyRecord);
var
  MyStore: TJvAppXMLFileStorage;
begin
  MyStore:= TJvAppXMLFileStorage.Create(nil);
  try
    MyStore.FileName:='C:\temp\record.xml';//point to the same file
    MyStore.Xml.LoadFromFile(MyStore.FileName); //load the file
    MyStore.ReadBinary('Dummy', @Rec,sizeof(Rec));//use the Dummy identifier and pass the record as an pointer
  finally
    MyStore.Free;
  end;
end;
```

### Check this full project (tested in Delphi 7)

```
program ProjectPersistRecord;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  JvAppXMLStorage;

type
  MyRecord= record
      Field1 : Integer;
      Field2 : Double;
      Field3 : String[20];
      Field4 : String[20];
  end;

Procedure SaveMyRecord(Rec : MyRecord);
var
  MyStore: TJvAppXMLFileStorage;
begin
  MyStore:= TJvAppXMLFileStorage.Create(nil);
  try
    MyStore.FileName:='C:\temp\record.xml';
    MyStore.WriteBinary('Dummy', @Rec,sizeof(Rec));
    MyStore.Xml.SaveToFile(MyStore.FileName);
  finally
    MyStore.Free;
  end;
end;

Procedure LoadMyRecord(var Rec : MyRecord);
var
  MyStore: TJvAppXMLFileStorage;
begin
  MyStore:= TJvAppXMLFileStorage.Create(nil);
  try
    MyStore.FileName:='C:\temp\record.xml';
    MyStore.Xml.LoadFromFile(MyStore.FileName);
    MyStore.ReadBinary('Dummy', @Rec,sizeof(Rec));
  finally
    MyStore.Free;
  end;
end;


Var
    Rec :  MyRecord;
begin
  //Fill the record
  Rec.Field1:=900;
  Rec.Field2:=7.8;
  Rec.Field3:='string test 1';
  Rec.Field4:='string test 2';
  SaveMyRecord(Rec); //save the record
  FillChar(Rec,SizeOf(Rec),#0); //clear the record variable
  LoadMyRecord(Rec);//restire the record data
  //show the loaded data
  Writeln(rec.field1);
  Writeln(rec.field2);
  Writeln(rec.field3);
  Writeln(rec.field4);
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: 84030000000000003333333333331F400D737472696E6720746573742031000000000000000D737472696E672074657374203200000000000000000000000000 maybe contains an Integer, a Double and two string[20], maybe not :) - Why not use a data transfer object to serialize to a real XML file, which is typesafe and supports versioning / compatibility, and also adds an "anti-corruption layer"?

Comment: Binary content to XML.  A perfect $$$$-storm of bad design decisions. Skip the XML if you're going to go binary.

Comment: @Warren XML adds the comfort of having a standard way of separating the binary data, and may also contain metadata like attributes. It is very robust regarding structure changes and also human readable (if the element names have self-documenting names)

Comment: Much better to write an RTTI-based Record-persistence layer that writes XML or JSON out and skip the binary here. This ain't no Picture we're transferring, it's a few integers and other scalar and string types.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Delphi 2010, you might want to take a look at [DeHL](http://code.google.com/p/delphilhlplib/).  It contains a serialization library that can handle pretty much any data type.

Comment: Just small note, that you can also do (de)serialization of ANY records/dynamic arrays in older Delphi versions too (of course pointers/interfaces/classes won't serialized, there is no such info in RTTI for records/dyn. arrays). I didn't saw any library for it, but made it some time ago. Hint: System.pas - _FinalizeXxx/_InitializeXxx

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, working from Delphi 5 up to XE2, is available [in one of our OpenSource unit](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/12/TDynArray-and-Record-compare/load/save-using-fast-RTTI).

In fact, it implements:

- Some low-level RTTI functions for handling record types: `RecordEquals, RecordSave, RecordSaveLength, RecordLoad`;
- A dedicated `TDynArray` object, which is a wrapper around any dynamic array, able to expose TList-like methods around any dynamic array, even containing records, strings, or other dynamic arrays. It's able to serialize any dynamic array.

Serialization uses an optimized binary format, and is able to save and load any record or dynamic array as `RawByteString`. You have also JSON serialization at hand, including custom layout - see [sustom JSON serialization of records](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/05/03/Custom-JSON-serialization-of-records).

Comment: update: the current version of the library will use the enhanced RTTI available since Delphi 2010 to serialize as JSON records and dynamic array contents. See http://blog.synopse.info/post/2014/05/18/Automatic-JSON-serialization-of-record-or-dynamic-arrays-via-Enhanced-RTTI  And the library is still heavily maintained, tested with XE6 on Win32 and Win64 platforms. For older versions of Delphi, you can define your record as plain text, since the standard RTTI does not provide enough information.

Answer (score 0):

Being a record, if you don't have properties, I don't believe you're any further ahead, trying to use any of the persistence frameworks (like DeHL).

The accepted answer, while technically correct, is dubious in real-world utility, and has many long term support-nightmare scenarios if you use it in production. DON'T DO IT.

If your program is just a bit of ad-hoc'ery, may I humbly suggest that you rock it old-school with a "file of record", a classic Turbo Pascal technique that still works.

Comment: what do you mean with "is dubious in real-world utility"? any examples?

Comment: Unfortunately file types do not support arrays. BTW the code that uses serialization does not go into production. This is just for the debugging. In particular I'm saving the result of the lengthy calculation, so I can load these results and start debugging a little faster. But it's a good tip, thanks. +1

Comment: Storing binary data inside XML has no advantage, and many real disadvantages as compared to just storing direct binary data either using `File Of Record` old-school, or a simple record-binary-writing-to-stream.