# how to read/write record types to send them via udp?

Tags: delphi, record

I have a `record` `type` with name, login, external-ip, tags and a boolean. I want to send that information to other computer via `UDP` where I want to get it back into a variable of the same record type.

I already know how to send and receive simple strings with Indy's UDPClient/UDPServer.

But how to send a record data?

I also want to, if possible, pass this data to my encryption method `codeSSL(s,k)` and when received, pass to `decodeSSL(s,k)` but I will be very satisfied if you could answer my first question, which is more important.

Comment: Serialize using one of the many many serialization libraries. For instance SuperObject.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a serialization library.
You can find some in this link, [Delphi (win32) serialization libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2984362/576719).

For a comparison benchmark between different serialization libraries, see [New sample for JSON performance: mORMot vs SuperObject/XSuperObject/dwsJSON/DBXJSON](http://blog.synopse.info/post/json-benchmark-delphi-mormot-superobject-dwsjson-dbxjson).

This is an example using [SuperObject](https://code.google.com/p/superobject/) for serializing/deserializing a record in a generic way.

```
program TestSerializer;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses SuperObject;

type
   Serializer = record
     class function Serialize<T>(data: T): String; static;
     class procedure Deserialize<T>(const jsonStr: String; var data: T); static;
   end;

class procedure Serializer.Deserialize<T>(const jsonStr: String; var data: T);
var
  ctx: TSuperRttiContext;
begin
  ctx := TSuperRttiContext.Create;
  try
    data := ctx.AsType<T>(SO(jsonStr));
  finally
    ctx.Free;
  end;
end;

class function Serializer.Serialize<T>(data: T): String;
var
  ctx: TSuperRttiContext;
  obj: ISuperObject;
begin
  Result := '';
  ctx := TSuperRttiContext.Create;
  try
    obj := ctx.AsJson<T>(data);
    Result := obj.AsJson;
  finally
    ctx.Free;
  end;
end;

type
  TData = record
    str: string;
    int: Integer;
    bool: Boolean;
    flt: Double;
  end;

var
  data: TData;
  jStr: String;
begin
  data.str := 'Test';
  data.int := 42;
  data.bool := True;
  data.flt := 3.14;
  jStr := Serializer.Serialize<TData>(data);
  WriteLn(jStr);
  data.str := '';
  Serializer.Deserialize<TData>(jStr,data);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

If you are using Indy, there is a `Send()` method for sending string data.

You can find some examples of string encryption/decryption here: [Delphi: simple string encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6798188/576719).

Answer (score 3):

On the sending side, you need to serialize your record data into a flat byte array, optionally encrypt those bytes, and then send them.  On the receiving side, you would read the bytes, optionally decrypt them, and then serialize them back into a record.  `TIdUDPClient` and `TIdUDPServer` has methods for reading/writing `TIdBytes` data, and the `IdGlobal` unit has functions for manipulating `TIdBytes` data.

For example:

Sender:

```
type
  TMyRecord = record
    Name: String;
    Login: String;
    ExternalIP: String;
    Tags: String;
    Flag: Boolean;
  end;

procedure AppendStringToBuffer(var Bytes: TIdBytes; const S: String);
var
  Tmp: TIdBytes;
  Len: Byte;
begin
  Tmp := ToBytes(S, enUTF8);
  Len := Length(Tmp);
  AppendByte(Bytes, Len);
  AppendBytes(Bytes, Tmp);
 end;

var
  Rec: TMyRecord;
  Buf: TIdBytes;
begin
  Rec := ...;

  AppendStringToBuffer(Buf, Rec.Name);
  AppendStringToBuffer(Buf, Rec.Login);
  AppendStringToBuffer(Buf, Rec.ExternalIP);
  AppendStringToBuffer(Buf, Rec.Tags);
  AppendByte(Buf, Ord(Rec.Flag));

  // optionally encrypt the buffer...

  MySocket.SendBuffer(TargetHost, TargetPort, Buf);
end;
```

Receiver:

```
type
  TMyRecord = record
    Name: String;
    Login: String;
    ExternalIP: String;
    Tags: String;
    Flag: Boolean;
  end;

function ReadStringFromBuffer(const Bytes: TIdBytes; var Index: Integer): String;
var
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Len := Bytes[Index];
  Inc(Index);
  if Len > 0 then
  begin
    Result := BytesToString(Bytes, Index, Len, enUTF8);
    Inc(Index, Len);
  end else
    Result := '';
 end;

var
  Rec: TMyRecord;
  Buf: TIdBytes;
  BufLen, Index: Integer;
  SenderIP: String;
  SenderPort: TIdPort;
begin
  SetLength(Buf, 1025);
  BufLen := MySocket.ReceiveBuffer(Buf, SenderIP, SenderPort);
  if Buf <= 0 then Exit;

  // optionally decrypt the buffer...

  Index := 0;
  Rec.Name := ReadStringFromBuffer(Buf, Index);
  Rec.Login := ReadStringFromBuffer(Buf, Index);
  Rec.ExternalIP := ReadStringFromBuffer(Buf, Index);
  Rec.Tags := ReadStringFromBuffer(Buf, Index);
  Rec.Flag := Buf[Index] <> $00;

  ...
end;
```